# How to display the result - MySQL problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to make right query.
I have a three tables:

1. **meals** - includes id_meals,name,description.
2. **ingredients** - includes id_ingredients,name
3. **Meals_Ingredients** - includes id_meals,id_ingredients

visualisation:

[simple visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdUfR.png)

How to display meals that contain ingredients with id_ingredients = 2 and id_ingredients = 3?

Pictures with more details:

[More details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDAjd.png)

So, for example, I would like to find all dishes that contain id_ingredients=2 (onion) and id_ingredients=3 (flour). But how? Please help me :)

I only found this:

```
SELECT id_meals, GROUP_CONCAT(id_ingredients) AS INGREDIENTS FROM Meals_Ingredients GROUP BY id_meals;
```

But this only show all ingredients in a meals.

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbleZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT id_meals, GROUP_CONCAT(id_ingredients) AS INGREDIENTS
FROM Meals_Ingredients
GROUP BY id_meals
HAVING SUM(id_ingredients = 2) > 0 AND
       SUM(id_ingredients = 3) > 0;
```

Note:  The above returns the meals with all ingredients.  If a recipe only has each ingredient once (no duplicates) and you only want the `id_meals`, then this is simpler:

```
SELECT id_meals, GROUP_CONCAT(id_ingredients) AS INGREDIENTS
FROM Meals_Ingredients
WHERE id_ingredients IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY id_meals
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if id_meals = 1 have for example id_ingredients 1,2,3,4 then your code where you use id_ingredients 2 and 3 also print the result for id_meals = 1 and it shouldn't. Because id_meals = 1 components are missing id_ingredients = 1 and id_ingredients = 4. You understand, you can't make a pizza when the ingredients are missing.

Comment: @Radzioxo . . . Your question is:  "How to display meals that contain ingredients with id_ingredients = 2 and id_ingredients = 3?"  That is _exactly_ what this does.  Are you saying that you really want:  "How to display meals that contain ingredients with id_ingredients = 2 and id_ingredients = 3 *and no others*?